# Unit Test Controller with Attribute

Tags: asp.net-core, xunit

I have an attribute that is applied to my controller. The Attribute reads data from cache or adds an item to the cache if its not found.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
internal sealed class CachedAttribute : Attribute, IAsyncActionFilter
{
    private readonly int _timeToLiveMinutes;

    public CachedAttribute(int timeToLiveMinutes)
    {
        _timeToLiveMinutes = timeToLiveMinutes;
    }

    public async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        var cacheService = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IResponseCacheService>();

        var cacheKey = GenerateCacheKeyFromRequest(context.HttpContext.Request);
        var cachedResponse = await cacheService.GetCachedResponseAsync(cacheKey);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cachedResponse))
        {
            var contentResult = new ContentResult
            {
                Content = cachedResponse,
                ContentType = "application/json",
                StatusCode = 200
            };
            context.Result = contentResult;

            return;
        }

        var executedContext = await next(); // move to controller

        if (executedContext.Result is ObjectResult objectResult)
        {
            await cacheService.CacheResponseAsync(cacheKey, objectResult.Value, _timeToLiveMinutes);
        }
    }

    private static string GenerateCacheKeyFromRequest(HttpRequest request)
    {
        var keyBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        keyBuilder.Append($"{request.Path}");

        foreach (var (key, value) in request.Query.OrderBy(x => x.Key))
        {
            keyBuilder.Append($"|{key}-{value}");
        }

        return keyBuilder.ToString();
    }
}
```

My first unit test works reading data from cache

```
  public async Task Cashed_attribute_gets_data_from_cache()
    {
        var mockCacheService = new Mock<IResponseCacheService>();
        mockCacheService.Setup(x => x.GetCachedResponseAsync(It.IsAny<string>()))
            .ReturnsAsync(() => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(GetTenantResponse()));

        mockCacheService.Setup(x => x.CacheResponseAsync(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<object>(), It.IsAny<int>()))
            .Returns(() => Task.CompletedTask);

        await using var provider = new ServiceCollection()
            .AddSingleton<IResponseCacheService>(_ => mockCacheService.Object)
            .BuildServiceProvider(true);

        var httpContext = new DefaultHttpContext
        {
            Request =
            {
                Path = "/somepath/identifier"
            },
            RequestServices = provider
        };

        var actionContext = new ActionContext(httpContext,
            new RouteData(),
            new ActionDescriptor(),
            new ModelStateDictionary());

        var actionExecutingContext = new ActionExecutingContext(actionContext,
            new List<IFilterMetadata>(),
            new Dictionary<string, object>(),
            controller: null);

        ActionExecutionDelegate mockDelegate = () => 
            Task.FromResult(new ActionExecutedContext(actionContext, new List<IFilterMetadata>(), null));

        var sut = new CachedAttribute(1);

        await sut.OnActionExecutionAsync(actionExecutingContext, mockDelegate);

        mockCacheService.Verify(x => x.GetCachedResponseAsync(It.IsAny<string>()), Times.Once());
        mockCacheService.Verify(x => x.CacheResponseAsync(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<object>(), 
                It.IsAny<int>()), Times.Never());

    }
```

My second unit test always fails as the ActionExecutionDelegate never sends the request to the controller action when the item in not found in the cache.

```
   [Fact]
    public async Task Cashed_attribute_adds_data_to_cache()
    {
        var mockCacheService = new Mock<IResponseCacheService>();
        mockCacheService.Setup(x => x.GetCachedResponseAsync(It.IsAny<string>()))
            .ReturnsAsync(() => string.Empty);

        mockCacheService.Setup(x => x.CacheResponseAsync(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<object>(), It.IsAny<int>()))
            .Returns(() => Task.CompletedTask);

        await using var provider = new ServiceCollection()
            .AddSingleton<IResponseCacheService>(_ => mockCacheService.Object)
            .BuildServiceProvider(true);

        var httpContext = new DefaultHttpContext
        {
            Request =
            {
                Path = "/somepath/identifier"
            },
            RequestServices = provider
        };

        var mockMediator = new Mock<IMediator>();
        mockMediator.Setup(x => x.Send(It.IsAny<GetTenantByIdentifierQuery>(),
                default))
            .ReturnsAsync(() => GetTenantResponse());

        var controller = new FinbuckleController(mockMediator.Object)
        {
            ControllerContext = new ControllerContext
            {
                HttpContext = new DefaultHttpContext
                {
                    RequestServices = provider
                }
            }
        };

        var actionContext = new ActionContext(httpContext,
            new RouteData(),
            new ActionDescriptor(),
            new ModelStateDictionary());

        var actionExecutingContext = new ActionExecutingContext(actionContext,
            new List<IFilterMetadata>(),
            new Dictionary<string, object>(),
            controller);

        ActionExecutionDelegate mockDelegate = () =>
            Task.FromResult(new ActionExecutedContext(actionContext, new List<IFilterMetadata>(), controller));

        var sut = new CachedAttribute(1);

        await sut.OnActionExecutionAsync(actionExecutingContext, mockDelegate);

        mockCacheService.Verify(x => x.GetCachedResponseAsync(It.IsAny<string>()), Times.Once());
        mockCacheService.Verify(x => x.CacheResponseAsync(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<object>(),
                It.IsAny<int>()), Times.Once());

    }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After a little more digging, I was able to set the Result property of the ActionExecuteContext. The ActionExecutionDelegate now returns an IActionResult, which can be added to the cache.

```
  [Fact]
    public async Task Cashed_attribute_adds_data_to_cache()
    {
        var mockCacheService = new Mock<IResponseCacheService>();
        mockCacheService.Setup(x => x.GetCachedResponseAsync(It.IsAny<string>()))
            .ReturnsAsync(() => string.Empty);

        mockCacheService.Setup(x => x.CacheResponseAsync(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<object>(), It.IsAny<int>()))
            .Returns(() => Task.CompletedTask);

        await using var provider = new ServiceCollection()
            .AddSingleton<IResponseCacheService>(_ => mockCacheService.Object)
            .BuildServiceProvider(true);

        var httpContext = new DefaultHttpContext
        {
            Request =
            {
                Path = "/somepath/identifier"
            },
            RequestServices = provider
        };

        var actionContext = new ActionContext(httpContext,
            new RouteData(),
            new ActionDescriptor(),
            new ModelStateDictionary());

        var actionExecutingContext = new ActionExecutingContext(actionContext,
            new List<IFilterMetadata>(),
            new Dictionary<string, object>(),
            null);

        var actionExecutedContext = new ActionExecutedContext(actionContext, new List<IFilterMetadata>(), null)
        {
            Result = new OkObjectResult(GetTenantResponse())
        };

        ActionExecutionDelegate mockDelegate = () =>
            Task.FromResult(actionExecutedContext);

        var sut = new CachedAttribute(1);

        await sut.OnActionExecutionAsync(actionExecutingContext, mockDelegate);

        mockCacheService.Verify(x => x.GetCachedResponseAsync(It.IsAny<string>()), Times.Once());
        mockCacheService.Verify(x => x.CacheResponseAsync(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<object>(),
                It.IsAny<int>()), Times.Once());

    }
```